# The right way to auto block ip's

Tags: iptables, fail2ban, ip-banning

The problem:

I manage a website which has lot's of dynamically generated pages.
Every day bots from Google, Yahoo and other search engines download like 100K+ of pages.
And sometimes i have problems with "hackers" trying to massively download the whole website.

I would like to block ip addresses of "hackers" while keeping search engine bots crawling the pages. What is the best way to do this ?

Note:
Right now i am solving the problem as follows. I save ip of each page request to a file every X seconds. And i have a crontab script which counts repetitive ip's every 30 minutes. For ip's which are repeated too many times, the script checks a hostname- if it doesn't belong to Google/Yahoo/Bing/etc then we have a candidate for banning.
But i don't really like my solution and think that auto banning could be done better or using some out of the box solution.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't state your OS, so I will happily tell you the OpenBSD version: in `pf.conf`
place something like the following in your ruleset (for 100 conns per 10 secs max):

```
table <bad_hosts> persist
block quick from <bad_hosts>
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to $webserver port www keep state \
                 (max-src-conn-rate 100/10, overload <bad_hosts> flush global)
```

you could add a whitelist and a cron job kicking addresses from bad_hosts after a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought fail2ban is the answer.

You can [use white list](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Whitelist)s to stop search engines getting blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Simple Event Correlator](http://simple-evcorr.sourceforge.net). It can automatically run commands (ie. add a block to `iptables`) after a certain amount of lines matching a regular expression have been seen within a window of time. It can also define a "context" that expires. When a context expires you can unblock the IP in question (ie. remove from `iptables`).